Why UE5 popups a SDK Not Setup error when I trying to build?
I trying to build a game on Windows 10 using UE5 and it show me a SDK Not Setup error.
Log is there:
LogTurnkeySupport: Running Turnkey device detection:  -ScriptsForProject="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/TheHallway.uproject" Turnkey -utf8output -WaitForUATMutex -command=VerifySdk -ReportFilename="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/Intermediate/TurnkeyReport_1.log" -log="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/Intermediate/TurnkeyLog_1.log" -project="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/TheHallway.uproject"  -Device=Win64@DESKTOP-4MQVNP0
LogMonitoredProcess: Running Serialized UAT: [ cmd.exe /c ""C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.4/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/RunUAT.bat"  -ScriptsForProject="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/TheHallway.uproject" Turnkey -utf8output -WaitForUATMutex -command=VerifySdk -ReportFilename="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/Intermediate/TurnkeyReport_1.log" -log="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/Intermediate/TurnkeyLog_1.log" -project="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/TheHallway.uproject"  -Device=Win64@DESKTOP-4MQVNP0" ]
LogTurnkeySupport: Completed device detection: Code = 255
LogTurnkeySupport: Warning: Turnkey failed to run properly, full Turnkey output:
Running AutomationTool...
Nie mo?na odnale?? okre?lonego pliku.
set DOTNET_ROOT=%UE_DOTNET_DIR%
rem Disables use of any installed version of dotnet
set DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP=1
rem for dotnet applications that require older dotnet runtimes, this will allow them to use our bundled dotnet runtime
set DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD=LatestMajor
rem skip dotnet verification when using our submitted sdk as we know it is up to date
ECHO Using bundled DotNet SDK version: %UE_DOTNET_VERSION%
Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
goto Succeeded
exit /B 0
LogMonitoredProcess: Running Serialized UAT: [ cmd.exe /c ""C:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_5.4/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/RunUAT.bat"  -ScriptsForProject="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/TheHallway.uproject" Turnkey -command=VerifySdk -UpdateIfNeeded -platform=Win64 -noturnkeyvariables -device=DESKTOP-4MQVNP0 -utf8output -WaitForUATMutex  -EditorIO -EditorIOPort=50369  -project="D:/UEE_Proj/TheHallway/TheHallway.uproject"" ]
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): Running AutomationTool...
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): Nie mo?na odnale?? okre?lonego pliku.
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): set DOTNET_ROOT=%UE_DOTNET_DIR%
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): rem Disables use of any installed version of dotnet
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): set DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP=1
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): rem for dotnet applications that require older dotnet runtimes, this will allow them to use our bundled dotnet runtime
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): set DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD=LatestMajor
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): rem skip dotnet verification when using our submitted sdk as we know it is up to date
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): ECHO Using bundled DotNet SDK version: %UE_DOTNET_VERSION%
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): goto Succeeded
UATHelper: Weryfikacja pakietu SDK i urządzenia (Windows): exit /B 0
LogSlate: Window Weryfikacja SDK being destroyed
LogUObjectHash: Compacting FUObjectHashTables data took   0.90ms
LogPlayLevel: Launcher Device ID: Windows@DESKTOP-4MQVNP0
LogPlayLevel: PlayLevel: No blueprints needed recompiling
LogLauncherProfile: Unable to find any targets for platform Windows - forcing build
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Running AutomationTool...
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Nie mo?na odnale?? okre?lonego pliku.
LogPlayLevel: UAT: set DOTNET_ROOT=%UE_DOTNET_DIR%
LogPlayLevel: UAT: 
LogPlayLevel: UAT: rem Disables use of any installed version of dotnet
LogPlayLevel: UAT: set DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP=1
LogPlayLevel: UAT: 
LogPlayLevel: UAT: rem for dotnet applications that require older dotnet runtimes, this will allow them to use our bundled dotnet runtime
LogPlayLevel: UAT: set DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD=LatestMajor
LogPlayLevel: UAT: 
LogPlayLevel: UAT: rem skip dotnet verification when using our submitted sdk as we know it is up to date
LogPlayLevel: UAT: ECHO Using bundled DotNet SDK version: %UE_DOTNET_VERSION%
LogPlayLevel: UAT: Using bundled DotNet SDK version: 6.0.302
LogPlayLevel: UAT: goto Succeeded
LogPlayLevel: Completed Launch On Stage: Launch Task, Time: 0.269243
LogPlayLevel: UAT: exit /B 0
PackagingResults: Error: Uruchomienie nieudane. Unknown Error
LogDerivedDataCache: C:/Users/jakub/AppData/Local/UnrealEngine/Common/DerivedDataCache: Maintenance finished in +00:00:00.000 and deleted 0 files with total size 0 MiB and 0 empty folders. Scanned 0 files in 1 folders with total size 0 MiB.
LogRemoteControlWebInterface: [Oczekujące] Uruchamianie interfejsu sieciowego zdalnego sterowania - Starting WebApp...
LogRemoteControlWebInterface: [Sukces] Interfejs sieciowego zdalnego sterowania jest aktywny - WebApp started, 127.0.0.1:30000
LogRemoteControlWebInterface: [Sukces] Interfejs sieciowego zdalnego sterowania jest aktywny - WebApp started, 127.0.0.1:30000
LogText3D: Text3D Engine Subsystem is clearing unreferenced cached fonts and typefaces.

Why turnkey fails? Please help me. I have a x64 CPU and
Installed a SDK and .net Core 3.1, copied hostfxr.dll to Engine\Binaries\DotNET\AutomationTool
